# How to use typeahead.js with the nested_form gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, typeahead.js

I have got Twitters [typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) working on my Rails 4 application. I also use the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem to dynamically add form fields in my view. The problem is that typeahead.js only works on text fields that exists at page load, not on the fields that are dynamically added after the page has loaded.

I found an answer that looks relevant at https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/224, but the answer involves editing the javascript code that dynamically adds the form elements.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use typeahead.js with the nested_form gem, or do I have to drop the gem and write my own code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can still use [`typeahead.js`](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) and [`nested_form gem`](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form), does this work for you?:

```
$(document).on('nested:fieldAdded', function(event){
  // this field was just inserted into your form
  var field = event.field; 
  // and activate typeahead on it
  field.typeahead({ /* ... */ });
})
```

So pretty much when the field is added, it will activate typeahead on it, just like https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/224 recommends.

Hope this helps

Comment: No, that didn't help. I tried to put the code both in the application.js and in the models own js file. I don't know much javascript, should I replace the comment in the last line with something or should it be like that?

Comment: What a dumb question you probably asked yourself ;) But I figured it out, I replaced /* ... */ with the javascript code that adds typeahead to the existing fields. Also, my nested_form inserts several fields, so I needed to find the correct field with a "var typeahead_field = field.find('.my_typeahead_class')", and activate typeahead on that variable instead of directly on the var field. Thank you @user2262149!